# How to display current time in DynamicTimeSeriesCollection in Jfreechart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

In my application i want to display current time in X axis of JFreechart. But it starts with 
00:00:00 . But actually i want like 06:15:30PM

I am setting timebase like this,

```
    final DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset =  new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 2 * 60, new Second());
    dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2011));
```

And setting DomainAxis like this,

```
    final XYPlot plot = Chart.getXYPlot();
    ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
    domain.setAutoRange(true);
```

My output is,

[image]

Comment: @trashgod, i am using the following code to genetare. but it will also start from 12:00:00 AM. Code is,                                    **DateAxis axis = (DateAxis)                           Plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setFixedAutoRange(60000);
        axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a"));**

Answer (score 0):

```
    Date date = new Date();
    Dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(date));
```

By using the above statements I resolved the problem.

Comment: hm not sure why I got wrong current time with this method though.
EX: Current time : 1:33 AM -> It displays 1:49
Any solutions?